# How to get XPath of all Nodes in XML by using Java or Scala?

Tags: java, xml, scala, xpath

I want to get XPath of all Nodes in XML by using Java or Scala ?

```
<foo>
    <foo1>Foo Test 1</foo1>
    <foo2>
        <another1>
            <test10>This is a duplicate</test10>
        </another1>
    </foo2>
    <foo2>
        <another1>
            <test1>Foo Test 2</test1>
        </another1>
    </foo2>
    <foo3>Foo Test 3</foo3>
    <foo4>Foo Test 4</foo4>
</foo>
```

**Output** :

```
foo
foo/foo2/
/foo/foo2/another1/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use [StAX parser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html). Consider following code:

```
public class XmlPathIterator implements Iterator<String> {
    private static XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    private final XMLStreamReader xmlReader;
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>(); // really need just Stack but it is old and Vector-based

    public XmlPathIterator(XMLStreamReader xmlReader) {
        this.xmlReader = xmlReader;
        moveNext();
    }

    public static XmlPathIterator fromInputStream(InputStream is) {
        try {
            return new XmlPathIterator(factory.createXMLStreamReader(is));
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static XmlPathIterator fromReader(Reader reader) {
        try {
            return new XmlPathIterator(factory.createXMLStreamReader(reader));
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void moveNext() {
        try {
            while (xmlReader.hasNext()) {
                int type = xmlReader.next();
                switch (type) {
                    case XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT:
                        tags.clear(); // finish
                        return;

                    case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                        QName qName = xmlReader.getName();
                        tags.add(qName.getLocalPart());
                        return;

                    case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                        tags.remove(tags.size() - 1);
                        break; // but continue the loop!

                    // also continue  the loop on everything else
                }
            }
        } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex); // just pass throw
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !tags.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        String cur = "/" + String.join("/", tags);
        moveNext();
        return cur;
    }
}
```

It is an iterator of `String` that returns XPath for each node. If your file is small and fits in memory, you can easily build a `List` from it.

Things that are not handled:

1. Namespaces (as your example has no) but you can modify how you generate `String` from `QName` in the `case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT`
2. Positional specificators in case there are several matching tags under the same path. If you want to get only unique strings, you may create a `Set` from this iterator to filter out duplicates.